# How to get year, month, day in UTC?

Tags: java, android, date

I have a some `Date` that was gotten by `Calendar.getInstance()` (in local time zone as I got).

```
public final class Converter {

    private static final TimeZone UTC_ZONE = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");

    private Converter() {

    }

    public static int toPackedUTCDate(Date date) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(UTC_ZONE);
        c.setTime(date);
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR); // UTC year
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH); // UTC month
        int dayOfMonth = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); // UTC day of month
        return TimeUtils.packDate(dayOfMonth, month, year);
    }
}
```

Of course, it's a wrong code but how to get a correct? Cuz `date` was gotten by `Calendar.getInstance().getTime()`. Sorry, I really can't get all these time zones... If someone can explain me clearly I will be very grateful.  I just need to the user could input his date (in his local time zone) and my app has stored as date in UTC in own packed format.

Comment: `Date` and `Calendar` are legacy classes and should not be used anymore.  The `java.time` package is more appropriate for date and time functions.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android in the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.now( ZoneOffset.UTC )
```

## java.time

You are using troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the *java.time* classes.

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

### Time zone

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may change at any moment, so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the JVM’s current default is applied implicitly. Better to be explicit.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

If you want UTC, use the constant defined as [`ZoneOffset.UTC`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#UTC).

```
LocalDate todayUtc= LocalDate.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

> Sorry, I really can't get all these time zones

These concepts have been covered many many times already on Stack Overflow, sometimes quite in-depth.

Search thoroughly before posting. Search for `Instant`, `ZoneId`, `ZoneOffset`, "java.time", `OffsetDateTime`, `ZonedDateTime`, `DateTimeFormatter`.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: Thank you for the backport library, it's very convenient.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Date date = new Date(year,month,day,hour,min);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    Date utc= new Date(sdf.format(date));
```

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android in the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).